# A clipboard manager that also supports images?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard, clipboard-manager

Most clipboard managers I found only support text to be stored in their clipboard history. Can someone please recommend me one that also stores images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Gnomes-based DE, Diodon is the clipboard manager you need. You can log into the settings of it and check "include images" and your photos will be in your history.

How to install with APT, according to [Diodon Github](https://github.com/diodon-dev/diodon):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y diodon
```

You can also use CopyQ. This joker has tons of options and capabilities.